# Show matrix is positive [semi]definite

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to show $H = (1-\rho)\mathbf{I} + \rho\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^\intercal$ is positive [semi]definite where $$\dfrac{-1}{n-1} < \rho < 1$$ where $\dim H = n\times n$

So far I have, for any $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ $$\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}^\intercal H \mathbf{x} &= (1-\rho)\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + \rho\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2\\
&= 
\end{align*}$$

Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: What is $I$ and what is $1^T$?

Comment: $\mathbf{I}$ is identity matrix, and $\mathbf{1}$ is vector of $1$s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Cauchy-Shwartz's inequality we have:
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}^\intercal H \mathbf{x} &= (1-\rho)\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + \rho\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2\\
&\geq \frac{(1-\rho)}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2 + \rho\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2\\
&=\frac{1+(n-1)\rho}{n}\left( \sum^n_{i=1} x_i^2\right)^2\\
&\geq 0
\end{align*}$$
and you are done (you have to assume that $n>1$ otherwise your $\rho$ could evaluate to $1/0$).

Comment: Cauchy Shwartz all day every day

Answer (score 3):

It is clear that the matrix is symmetric.  It suffices, therefore, to show that its eigenvalues are non-negative.

Note that the eigenvalues of $11^T$ are $0$ and $n$.  Thus, the eigenvalues of $H$ must be $1-\rho$, and $(1 - \rho) + \rho n = 1 + (n-1) \rho$ respectively.  Note that both of these must be non-negative.